# Realloc() introduces random values in my dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays, realloc

UPDATE: Not a duplicate. As Kamil Cuk pointed out in the comments I should have used memcpy() instead of assigning a pointer! Thanks for your time

I am writing a dynamic array using `realloc()` to scale it. In my function `addToList()` I add correct values to correct pointers (check program output) but when I use `getFromList()` and print out all the values previously assigned, most of them are correct but some are wrong (check output), strangely the amount of wrong values is equal to how many times `realloc()` was used but these values are at completely random intervals! (`realloc()` exits successfully). I have no idea why these random values pop up, any help will be highly appreciated

Calling these functions:

```
//TEST
arrayList list;
if(initList(&list,sizeof(int))!=0){
    printf("List init failed");
    exit(1);
}
int tempNum = 38;
int i = 0;
while(1){
    tempNum+=1;
    if(addToList(&list,&tempNum)!=0){
        printf("Failed to add to list");
        exit(1);
    }
    //sleep(1);

    //Break after 31 values assigned
    if(i>=30){
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
//Print the 31 values previously assigned
for(int i = 0;i<=30;i++){
    //Get data at index
    int *num = NULL;
    num = getFromList(&list,i);
    //Check errors
    if(num==NULL){
        //ERROR
        exit(1);
    }
    //Print data
    printf("Data: %i  ",*num);
    printf("Location in memory: %i\n", num);
}
```

Function definitions:

```
int initList(arrayList *arrayLst, size_t dataSize){
    printf("Initializing a list\n");
    //Allocate memory for list struct itself
    arrayLst = memset(arrayLst,0, sizeof(arrayLst));

    //Allocate memory for first block (depends on increments defined in .h file)
    char *tempDataMallocPtr;
    if((tempDataMallocPtr = malloc((arrayLst->dataSize)*listIncrement))==NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    arrayLst->data = tempDataMallocPtr;

    //Initialize values
    arrayLst->length = 0;
    arrayLst->dataSize = dataSize;
    arrayLst->allocated = listIncrement;

    return 0;

}

int addToList(arrayList *arrayLst, void *data){

    //Check if enough space
    if(arrayLst->allocated > arrayLst->length){
        //Enough memory
        //printf("Enough memory\n");
    }else{
        //Reallocating memory
        printf("Not enough memory reallocating\n");
        printf("New memory size = %i\n", ((arrayLst->allocated)*(arrayLst->dataSize) + (arrayLst->dataSize)*listIncrement));
        fflush(stdout);
        int newSize = (arrayLst->allocated)*(arrayLst->dataSize) + (arrayLst->dataSize)*listIncrement;
        char *tempReallocPtr;
        //Realloc() error checking
        if ((tempReallocPtr = realloc((arrayLst->data), newSize))==NULL){
            printf("Realloc failed in arrayList\n");
            return 1;
        }
        arrayLst->data = tempReallocPtr;
        arrayLst->allocated = newSize/(arrayLst->dataSize);
    }

    //Get pointer for last data index and set it to data provided
    printf("Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = %i    ", (arrayLst->data)+((arrayLst->length)*(arrayLst->dataSize)));
    printf("data being added %i    ",*((char*)data));
    *((arrayLst->data)+((arrayLst->length)*(arrayLst->dataSize))) = *((char*)data);
    (arrayLst->length)+=1;

    printf("Added to list\n");
    //Success
    return 0;

}

void* getFromList(arrayList *arrayLst, int index){
    //Check if index correct
    if(index<(arrayLst->length) && index>=0){
        //Correct
        return (arrayLst->data+index*(arrayLst->dataSize));
    }else{
        //ERROR
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong index in arrayList\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

arrayList typedef:

```
typedef struct _arrayList{
    char *data;
    size_t dataSize;
    int allocated; //Memory allocated
    int length;  //Numbers inside the list 
}arrayList;
```

Output:

```
gcc -o server.exe server.c arrayList.c
./server.exe
Initializing a list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895424    data being added 39    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895420    data being added 40    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895416    data being added 41    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895412    data being added 42    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895408    data being added 43    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 40
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895404    data being added 44    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895400    data being added 45    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895396    data being added 46    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895392    data being added 47    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895388    data being added 48    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 60
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895384    data being added 49    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895380    data being added 50    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895376    data being added 51    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895372    data being added 52    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895368    data being added 53    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 80
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895364    data being added 54    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895360    data being added 55    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895356    data being added 56    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895352    data being added 57    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895348    data being added 58    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 100
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895344    data being added 59    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895340    data being added 60    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895336    data being added 61    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895332    data being added 62    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895328    data being added 63    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 120
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895324    data being added 64    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895320    data being added 65    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895316    data being added 66    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895312    data being added 67    Added to list
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895308    data being added 68    Added to list
Not enough memory reallocating
New memory size = 140
Adding data at pointer: Pointer address = -78895304    data being added 69    Added to list
Data: 39  Location in memory: -78895424
Data: 40  Location in memory: -78895420
Data: 41  Location in memory: -78895416
Data: 42  Location in memory: -78895412
Data: 43  Location in memory: -78895408
Data: 44  Location in memory: -78895404
Data: 133421  Location in memory: -78895400
Data: 46  Location in memory: -78895396
Data: 47  Location in memory: -78895392
Data: 48  Location in memory: -78895388
Data: 133425  Location in memory: -78895384
Data: 50  Location in memory: -78895380
Data: 51  Location in memory: -78895376
Data: 52  Location in memory: -78895372
Data: 53  Location in memory: -78895368
Data: 54  Location in memory: -78895364
Data: 55  Location in memory: -78895360
Data: 56  Location in memory: -78895356
Data: 133433  Location in memory: -78895352
Data: 58  Location in memory: -78895348
Data: 59  Location in memory: -78895344
Data: 60  Location in memory: -78895340
Data: 133181  Location in memory: -78895336
Data: 62  Location in memory: -78895332
Data: 63  Location in memory: -78895328
Data: 64  Location in memory: -78895324
Data: 133185  Location in memory: -78895320
Data: 66  Location in memory: -78895316
Data: 67  Location in memory: -78895312
Data: 68  Location in memory: -78895308
Data: 133189  Location in memory: -78895304
```

Comment: You cant print an address with `%i` use `%p`.

Comment: realloc doesn't allocate empty memory, it just reserves a block of memory for use, with whatever is already in that memory area.  If you want it to be cleared then you should memset the new area with 0 before use.

Comment: Shouldn't you in `data beeing added` do `memcpy(&arrayLst->data[arrayLst->length * arrayLst->dataSize], data, arrayLst->dataSize);`. You are assigning just one byte there, thought arrayLst->data represent an array each of arrayLst->dataSize size. You are just lucky that you are assinging int's and all the other bytes are zero.

Comment: Instead of `arrayLst = memset(arrayLst,0, sizeof(arrayLst));`, I'd expect `memset(arrayLst,0, sizeof *arrayLst);`.  (Notice size part)

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, that solved it. I always tend to make stupid mistakes :) Thank you for your time and advice everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate memory through `malloc`, or increasing the amount through `realloc`, the contents of the (new) memory is *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Don't use it except to initialize it.